# Join query that gets members of a group, and then gets groups as query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have a website build in Laravel.
I have two tables - Groups and Group members.

For each `group_member`, the row in the table has `id`, `group_id` and `user_id`.

The groups have a name and a description.

When a user joins a group, a row is created in the `group_member` table.

But I now need to get the groups that a user is part of.

So if I have `user_id` = `5`, I need to get all the rows in `group_member` where `user_id = 5`, and then get the corresponding group, so I can query the groups.

I need to do something like `$groups = Groups::whereGroup_member` ...
But I cant query the model like that, because in `Groups` there is no where it specificies who the members are, it is just the group details - the members are specificed in `group_member` table.

How do I get the groups, which a member is part of using the laravel query standards?

Comment: What about `$groups = User::find(5)->groups`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User.php` Model

```
public function group_member(){
     return $this->hasMany(GroupMember::class,'user_id','id;);
}
```

In your `GroupMember.php` Model

```
public function group(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Group::class,'group_id','id');
}
```

Your query will be

```
$users = User::with('group_member.group')->find($user_id);
```

Comment: Hi,

I cant get this to work. Im not sure how this would get the groups based on the rows in group_members where the user_id = Auth::user()->id --> and then get the groups back so I can loop trough the groups within a foreach statement

Comment: did you try the above code? what did you got? can you post it?

Comment: You cannot do `Groups::whereGroup_member..` as you specified in your question because it does not contain any foreign key.

Comment: If i Change $user_id in the query to $user->id which I need it to be, and change Group::class to Groups::class and GroupMember to Groupmember I get ErrorException in 67186d94192d77804e3ae5e4e7abf3eba52a7e94.php line 29: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/timebuddy.dk/resources/views/dashboard/groups/index.blade.php)

Comment: And with this I could guess that I get the users, but thats not what I need, i need the groups from the group model

Comment: do `print_r($users->toArray());` tell me what are you getting?

Comment: I get Undefined variable: users

Comment: did you save the query in `$users` variable? look at my updated answer

Comment: So with this I get the user data - but what I need is the group data.

Comment: `with('group_member.group')` this will get you the user `group_member` row and to which `group` does user is associated with. This technique is called as Eager Loading. Refer to this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

You should use Many-to-Many relation:

```
class Group
...
public function members() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class); // Users (members) that belongs to Group
}

class User
...
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'group_member', 'user_id', 'group_id'); // Groups that User belongs to
}
```

And at controller, when You have user id:

```
 $groups = User::where('id', $user_id)->groups;
```

More about this written at official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: This doesn't even contain the group_members table, so this is rendered unusable